# Handle64.exe Makes Ping Very Jittering and High?

Tags: windows-7, networking, wireless-networking

I was playing online games such as CS:GO and Battlefield Hardline / 4, when every now and then (more often than not) my local area network (LAN) and online ping times would drastically raise with about a 100ms to 300ms jitter. I have tries fixing this problem by buying a new modem not owned by TWC and registering it and also buying an new Netgear AC1600 router. Just to mention I don't use wifi, I use ethernet. One strange day my dad's computer was at shop for a broken screen after dropping it. For the few days after the internet latency times were much, much better than I had seen in a long while 42ms or lower pinging to the mid-east of the US (Live in Florida). I also saw that my latency was superior to my friends' internet at that time too, even though they live not even a few blocks away. Then the computer was back and all of a sudden the issues came back too. I knew at that point it was my dads computer was the issue but I still didn't know exactly what was the issue specifically. I *think* I have narrowed it down to a media player called PlayItAll media, in which is no longer available due ti all installers being online and their website not being up to get the files from. To mention that he is a heavy torrenter (which is not the problem), he likes watching many movies. As of many times when he started up this media player the latency would spike to 300ms from ~60ms and seconds later have jitter of about ~100 - ~300ms. Shutting this program off had no affect. A few minutes later after shutting it off the issues were still there. I looked into the task manager and saw a weird process I have never seen on its own called ***"Handle64.exe"***. Once this was shut off, viola the issues were gone. I'm not sure as to what this is associated with, but my idea is that this came with PlayItAll.

**If anyone knows about *Handle64.exe*, anymore than me than please explain as to what this is actually doing and how it is affecting our whole entire network.**

Thank you for all of your help!

Answer (score 0):

1) torrents can saturate a connection, especially upload;

2) playitall looks like malware or even ransom ware. "They" say it thrashes all your file associations and kills restore points if you uninstall it. In any event get rid of it, possibly manually ( [Post Discussing Removal](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_xp-windows_programs/problem-uninstalling-playitall-media-player/b83defcc-b48a-46a0-8fbf-611744596539) )

> [...] using Add and remove programs to uninstall caused the
>   computer to be unusable until I restored it, which brought Play it all
>   back [...]
>
> [...]someone said
>   it's NOT a VIRUS but a poorly written uninstall that [messed up] the re-associating of file extensions.
>
> [...] we [opened] the folder and deleted the uninstall then the
>   rest of the files a few at a time, then ran Spybot's registry tool,
>   and did a manual search through the registry and all seems well.

There is a program called handle.exe which spawns handle64.exe on 64 bit systems. [Microsoft Sysinternals Handle](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896655.aspx). The well-known "Process Explorer" is the "gui-based version of this program."